# saving a file which contains dates results in keeping only last values

Tags: android

I  am using the following code to store in a file  some data.
(mydata is the data the user enters (double list) and  dates_Strings is a string list where i store dates)

```
public void savefunc(){

        SimpleDateFormat thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.US); 
        Date d=new Date();  

        String formattedDate=thedate.format(d);
        Log.d("tag","format"+formattedDate);
        dates_Strings.add(formattedDate);



            double thedata=Double.parseDouble(value.getText().toString().trim()); 
            mydata.add(thedata);


      File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File directory = new File (sdCard, "MyFiles");
        directory.mkdirs();            
        File file = new File(directory, filename);

        FileOutputStream fos;


        try {
           fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

              BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
              for (int i=0;i<mydata.size();i++){
                    bw.write(mydata.get(i)+","+dates_Strings.get(i)+"\n");
              }
              value.setText("");
              bw.flush();
              bw.close();

            } catch (IOException e2) {
               e2.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
```

The problem is that if I enter some data in 06/05/13 and later some data in 07/05/13 , the file contains only the last data from the last date.I want to keep all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the fileoutputstream in append mode

```
 fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);` to append data to the file instead of overwriting it.

[FileOutputStream documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)